# GQL Query Object Memory Leak

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-leaks, gql

I have a long running background process that parses a few hundred thousand lines of a CSV. I noticed that the process has a memory leak that occasionally causes the task to hit its soft memory limit and terminate. I have narrowed the section of code down to the following chunk of code:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    _keyNamespace = 'MyApp.Models'

    @classmethod
    def get_by_item_id(cls, id):
        key = "%s_%d" % (cls._keyNamespace, id)
        item = CacheStrategy.get(key)
        if not item:
            query = cls.gql("WHERE Id = :1", id)
            item = query.get()
            del query

        return item
```

I've cut this down to the bare bones but it is still causing Query objects to remain in memory. A sample GC reference dump is included at the end of the comment showing the Query and Query_Filter counts increase by 200 after every 200 order batch step. If i get rid of the query call, this of course goes away.

My question is, ***WHY*** is this leaking Query references and how do I get it to honour the del and drop the query reference?

I've tried making this an instance method (no difference). Reference count trace below:

```
INFO     2011-10-17 16:29:39,158 orderparser.py:151] Putting a 200 unit batch of orders, 0.335000 seconds from start
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,315 memleaker.py:20] Top Mem Leaks
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]     356306 Property
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]     356305 PropertyValue
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]      74410 Path
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]      74408 Path_Element
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]      45127 PropertyValue_ReferenceValue
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]      45127 PropertyValue_ReferenceValuePathElement
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,334 memleaker.py:22]      43822 Reference
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]      30595 EntityProto
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]        320 ProtocolMessage
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]        217 Query
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]        209 Query_Filter
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]         55 NOT_PROVIDED
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]         34 Index_Property
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,335 memleaker.py:22]         28 ExtendableProtocolMessage
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:40,336 memleaker.py:22]         18 CompositeIndex
INFO     2011-10-17 16:29:40,644 orderparser.py:151] Putting a 200 unit batch of orders, 1.821000 seconds from start
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,930 memleaker.py:20] Top Mem Leaks
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]     356506 Property
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]     356505 PropertyValue
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]      74410 Path
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]      74408 Path_Element
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]      45127 PropertyValue_ReferenceValue
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]      45127 PropertyValue_ReferenceValuePathElement
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,948 memleaker.py:22]      43822 Reference
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]      30595 EntityProto
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]        417 Query
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]        409 Query_Filter
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]        320 ProtocolMessage
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]         55 NOT_PROVIDED
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]         34 Index_Property
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,951 memleaker.py:22]         28 ExtendableProtocolMessage
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:41,953 memleaker.py:22]         18 CompositeIndex
INFO     2011-10-17 16:29:42,276 orderparser.py:151] Putting a 200 unit batch of orders, 3.450000 seconds from start
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,565 memleaker.py:20] Top Mem Leaks
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]     356706 Property
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]     356705 PropertyValue
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]      74410 Path
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]      74408 Path_Element
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]      45127 PropertyValue_ReferenceValue
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]      45127 PropertyValue_ReferenceValuePathElement
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,585 memleaker.py:22]      43822 Reference
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]      30595 EntityProto
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]        617 Query
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]        609 Query_Filter
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]        320 ProtocolMessage
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]         55 NOT_PROVIDED
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]         34 Index_Property
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,586 memleaker.py:22]         28 ExtendableProtocolMessage
DEBUG    2011-10-17 16:29:43,588 memleaker.py:22]         18 CompositeIndex
```

Comment: Are you using AppEngine for Business or normal AppEngine?

Comment: Well, because the Business platform had constant and serious trouble with the datastorage, but I never had problems with the normal AppEngine.

Comment: @daemonfire300 App Engine for Business is no longer a separate product, and hasn't been for some time. Also, the two platforms used the same datastore backend.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using key names for this? This would allow you to skip doing queries altogether, and just do a batch fetch for each batch, which would be a lot more efficient. Also, what tool are you using to detect memory leaks?

Comment: @Nick Through ignorance :) I have updated my code to use the passed ID as a key_name and now batch it up. This resolves the memory leak in my code from the query but i'm now leaking handles to a class named Reference, still digging into this. Also, i'm still curious about getting to the bottom of the question. I'm counting live references using a small hacked up GC script - http://snipt.net/Wolfwyrd/simple-reference-leak-finder

Comment: @Wolfwyrd I'm curious about the source of this, too, but unfortunately I don't have any ideas as to the cause. The classes in question are Protocol Buffers, and they shouldn't have circular references, the main cause of something like this. Does calling `gc.collect()` remove the leaked references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this using your refcount code and a trivial snippet below (on shell.appspot.com or a fresh app):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import logging
import sys
import types

def get_refcounts():
    d = {}
    # collect all classes
    for m in sys.modules.values():
        for sym in dir(m):
            o = getattr (m, sym)
            if type(o) is types.ClassType:
                d[o] = sys.getrefcount (o)
    # sort by refcount
    pairs = map (lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), d.items())
    pairs.sort()
    pairs.reverse()
    return pairs

def print_top(num = 15):
    print 'Top Mem Leaks'
    for n, c in get_refcounts()[:num]:
        print '%10d %s' % (n, c.__name__)

class TestModel(db.Model):
  id = db.IntegerProperty()


print_top()

q = TestModel.gql("WHERE id = :1", 1)
item = q.get()
del q

print_top()
```

It seems likely that something in your environment is holding references to the queries that have been executed. Are you using appstats or another development or debugging tool? Can you create a minimum reproduction case that exhibits the behaviour you observed?